# Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE response size. Received 7. LARAVEL ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, mariadb

I have a blog that is developed using laravel. In my local PC, everything is okay. But when I upload it in live shared hosting server it throws error like below:

```
ErrorException in MySqlConnector.php line 124:
Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE response size. Received 7
```

My server configuration is given below

> 1. Server: MariaDB
> 2. Server version: 10.1.20-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
> 3. PHP 5.6

I could not find any solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution.?

Comment: Last Two days I am tired with it. But I did not get any solution

Comment: Let's see the code around line 124.

Comment: There is a solution in the following link and it works
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938610/laravel-5-4-gives-wrong-com-stmt-prepare-response-size

Comment: I'm also having this same issue having PHP 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem. My web host provider was 000webhost. Just set this PDO attribute `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to true in your database config file (config/database.php) and it should work fine.

Eg:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    //.......
    'options'   => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,]
],
```

Additionally, you may need to run `php artisan config:cache` if you have cached your configuration or if running in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Inside both 
(1) /bootstrap/cache/config.php
(2) /config/database.php

For your particular database-server driver you need to add:

```
'options' => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true]
```

For example:

```
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => '3306',
//.....
'options' => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true]
```

but please not you have to add it in both files:

1. /bootstrap/cache/config.php
2. /config/database.php

because when I added it just inside /config/database.php I kept getting the same error, so after hours of googling around, I realized it is because this /bootstrap/cache/config.php is sort of a cache file made from Laravel .env file and /config/database.php and other files,  and this cache file seems to be made only once when you set the API_KEY thing inside .env file with php artisan key:generate.

Answer (score -1):

After researching everywhere I came to conclusion that the problem is in the database engine of the shared hosting, maybe a permission or something, so the solution I found was to **create the database in a separate service**. I used sql9.freemysqlhosting.net and is working fine so far.

note: This idea above is copied from another person but i tried it, and it works successfully

Comment: Please provide a link to the answer you referred to instead of duplicating.

Comment: ok .. but there isn't solution on the link more than that i have copied