# ErrorException in MySqlConnector.php line 124: Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE response size. Received 7

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I upload all laravel files on 000webhost. Create a DB and import DB in phpmyadmin. but i'm getting above error at 000webhost.

Comment: Perhaps you would be so kind as to include the code around line 124 in the question.

Comment: i found error and i fix it. please read on this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953626/wrong-com-stmt-prepare-response-size-received-7-laravel-error

Comment: i have the same problem, but i fixed it base on this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953626/wrong-com-stmt-prepare-response-size-received-7-laravel-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution itself.

It is just because of 000webhost does not support this laravel version.

Answer (score 1):

First, that's the wrong way to ask a question on **Stackoverflow** 
Second, you can find the sql hostname,username and password within your hosting control panel, and change it **.env**

Comment: I have changed and I know It's not proper way. still getting same problem @Rezrazi